# Will too thorough answers prevent users from upvoting?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, up-votes

Somehow the answers I put most effort in are not upvoted (even though the comments show that users agree). Now I have the idea that maybe they are too thorough and long? For example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378843/cloning-in-java/7379142#comment-8908783).

What do you think, is this the case? If not, can you give me any advice (I did read the faq and [How to upvote responsibly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59828/how-to-upvote-responsibly))?

Comment: So yours is a problem of TL;DR :-)

Comment: Yes, it definitely was. But now it's just awesome ;)

Comment: +1 (on SO) for `dvorakTyping`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What do you think, is this the case?

Generally, yes, although there *are* examples to the contrary - very highly upvoted foot-long answers. Much depends on whether the lot of content is truly essential, or just bloat (or related and on-topic, but peripheral information).

> If not, can you give me any advice

Some general rules that come to my mind:

- The first thing to do is obviously see whether there is any bloat. Is there a way to express things with less words, without becoming too cryptic of course?
- Sometimes it is necessary to trim legitimate content because it is simply too much to digest. Check each sentence for whether it's *really* necessary to answer the question.
- Text ***formatting***, headings, bullet points, and images can help make a long answer more digestible.
- Adding a tl;dr summary at the top or the bottom of the answer can sometimes also be helpful.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I followed your advise on my particular example - let's see whether people keep on up-voting the question and not my answer...

Comment: .... and it works :)

Comment: Wow, images make a huge difference, as you can see by my best answer by far, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7398703/linked-list-loop-detection-algorithm/7398882#7398882. Thanks again (+2 if I could ;)

Answer (score 2):

There was a graph that was showing [average votes on answers with different length](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104102/why-is-there-such-score-volatility-above-2k-character-answers), and the shortest answers were the most upvoted.

Problem is that a lot of users going through answers just fly around and they don't want to read such a long answers.

For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301261/how-to-see-mysql-query-error-details/7301273#7301273) one is easy, short and is most upvoted.

Try to at least add a summary of your answer (write about your answer in one line) to make users more interested in reading it.

Comment: “The shortest answers were the most upvoted” is misleading. It's true that *extremely short* answers (about one sentence long) are pretty highly upvoted, but after that, the longer an answer is, the more upvotes it tends to get, in a pretty steady pattern (about 0.8 upvote per 1000 characters).