# are there statistics about the features of accepted answers?

Tags: discussion

Are there any statistics (perhaps queries to run against the database) about what features appear often in accepted answers?

For example; do most accepted answers have less than, or more than, X words?  (I'm struggling for the language here.  Sorry.  I welcome corrections and suggestions for proper terminology.)

Graphs of the bell curves for "number of words" (on X axis) vs "number of upvotes" would be (I think) awesome.

I'm sure other people would have better ideas for what features commonly appear in accepted (or heavily upvoted) answers - amount of formatting; number of paragraphs; length of words, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I crated a modified Average Answer Score by Content Length query to include only accepted answers, available here:

[Average Accepted Answer Score by Content Length](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/112838/average-accepted-answer-score-by-content-length)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) for this.  If you search around, there are already lots of example queries to get you started.  [Phrogz](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/153741/phrogz) showed [one example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104102/why-is-there-such-score-volatility-above-2k-character-answers) where he created a plot of the [Average Answer Score by Content Length](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qe/1786/average-answer-score-by-content-length).  That query shouldn't take too much work to modify for only accepted answers.